# Why is the following C++ code printing only the first character?

Tags: c++, string, wchar

I am trying to convert a char string to a wchar string.

In more detail: I am trying to convert a char[] to a wchar[] first and then append " 1" to that string and the print it.

```
char src[256] = "c:\\user";

wchar_t temp_src[256];
mbtowc(temp_src, src, 256);

wchar_t path[256];

StringCbPrintf(path, 256, _T("%s 1"), temp_src);
wcout << path;
```

But it prints just `c`

Is this the right way to convert from char to wchar? I have come to know of another way since. But I'd like to know why the above code works the way it does?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`mbtowc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yk02bkxb.aspx) converts only a single character. Did you mean to use [`mbstowcs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1f9b8cy.aspx)?

Typically you call this function twice; the first to obtain the required buffer size, and the second to actually convert it:

```
#include <cstdlib> // for mbstowcs

const char* mbs = "c:\\user";
size_t requiredSize = ::mbstowcs(NULL, mbs, 0);
wchar_t* wcs = new wchar_t[requiredSize + 1];
if(::mbstowcs(wcs, mbs, requiredSize + 1) != (size_t)(-1))
{
    // Do what's needed with the wcs string
}
delete[] wcs;
```

If you rather use [`mbstowcs_s`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eyktyxsx.aspx) (because of deprecation warnings), then do this:

```
#include <cstdlib> // also for mbstowcs_s

const char* mbs = "c:\\user";
size_t requiredSize = 0;
::mbstowcs_s(&requiredSize, NULL, 0, mbs, 0);
wchar_t* wcs = new wchar_t[requiredSize + 1];
::mbstowcs_s(&requiredSize, wcs, requiredSize + 1, mbs, requiredSize);
if(requiredSize != 0)
{
    // Do what's needed with the wcs string
}
delete[] wcs;
```

Make sure you take care of locale issues via [setlocale()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x99tb11d.aspx) or using the versions of `mbstowcs()` (such as `mbstowcs_l()` or `mbstowcs_s_l()`) that takes a locale argument.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: Thanks. Appreciate it. :-)

Comment: Note that everything inside the `if` must not throw otherwise you'll leak. Probably a better idea to use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: @Gene Bushuyev: D'oh! I'm used to writing wrappers for resources, so I don't write `delete` or `delete[]` often. :-) Thanks for pointing that out. @Billy ONeal: Right, some form of RAII might be useful for this if the OP intends to do anything that may throw exceptions within the `if` block.

Answer (score 2):

why are you using C code, and why not write it in a more portable way, for example what I would do here is use the STL!

```
std::string  src = std::string("C:\\user") +
                   std::string(" 1");
std::wstring dne = std::wstring(src.begin(), src.end());

wcout << dne;
```

it's so simple it's easy :D

Comment: +1 True, your code also looks more elegent. But I am just learning my way around C and C++ (not production code). So I am deliberately fooling around with stuff. Motive is to understand how things work but not to simply get them done the better way :) Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

L"Hello World"

the prefix L in front of the string makes it a wide char string.

Comment: True, but it would make the problem trivial instead of calling conversion functions...

Comment: Actually, char src is something I am not in control of. Should have mentioned in the question. So I cannot add L in front of it. It is just some parameter I am being passed. But I put the code the way I did to keep things simple :)